# Can't add CloudRun as add-on when creating a GKE cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, serverless, google-cloud-run

I'm trying out Cloud Run with GKE, was wondering about this error:

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.container.clusters.create) argument --addons:
CloudRun must be one of [HttpLoadBalancing, HorizontalPodAutoscaling,
KubernetesDashboard, Istio, NetworkPolicy]

It seems it won't let me use CloudRun as an addon, I'm just creating a cluster.

Whole command is:

```sh
gcloud beta container clusters create testcloudrun \
--addons=HorizontalPodAutoscaling,HttpLoadBalancing,Istio,CloudRun \
--machine-type=n1-standard-4 \
--cluster-version=1.12.6-gke.16 --zone=us-central1-a \
--enable-stackdriver-kubernetes --enable-ip-alias \
--scopes cloud-platform
```

I'm just following the quick-start from the docs:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/prebuilt-deploy-gke

~~
Update:

I've tried creating a cluster via Cloud Console, and I'm getting an error:
`Horizontal pod autoscaling must be enabled in order to enable the Cloud Run addon.`

Which is a known issue as well:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues

Comment: It did not work for me on 1.12.6-gke.16. However it worked on 1.11.8-gke.6. I have already sent feedback for 1.12.6-gke.16.

Comment: still getting an error on 1.11.8-gke.6 https://monosnap.com/file/IMmM9UQFHok1EGaIUFVL2XkmbgXGKi

Comment: On console UI, beside create you will see your "command line" on cluster creation. Select your choices, however before you create copy and paste in cloudshell.

Comment: @danL that works! TIL there's a button to output a command line if you started with a console. The command line on docs still doesn't work though.